# Creating DataFrame with list of dictionaries with np.array values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dictionary, dataframe

I have a list of dictionaries with values that are returned as numpy arrays (and which are often empty).

```
data=[{'width': array([])},
      {'width': array([])},
      {'width': array([])},
      {'width': array([])},
      {'width': array([])},
      {'width': array([ 0.64848222])},
      {'width': array([ 0.62241745])},
      {'width': array([ 0.76892571])},
      {'width': array([ 0.69913647])},
      {'width': array([ 0.7506934])},
      {'width': array([ 0.69087949])},
      {'width': array([ 0.65302866])},
      {'width': array([ 0.67267989])},
      {'width': array([ 0.63862089])}]
```

I would like to create a DataFame were the values are floats and not of numpy array dtype. Also I'd like to the empty arrays to be converted to NaN values.

I have tried using `df=pd.DataFrame(data, dtype=float)` which returns a DataFame with values as np.arrays as such:

```
               width
0                 []
1                 []
2                 []
3                 []
4                 []
5   [0.648482224582]
6   [0.622417447245]
7   [0.768925710479]
8   [0.699136467373]
9    [0.75069339816]
10  [0.690879488242]
11  [0.653028655088]
12  [0.672679885077]
13  [0.638620890633]
```

I've also tried recasting the df's values after creating it using `df.values.astype(float)` but get the following error:
`ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

The final output I am trying to get for the DataFame looks like:

```
               width
0                NaN
1                NaN
2                NaN
3                NaN
4                NaN
5     0.648482224582
6     0.622417447245
7     0.768925710479
8     0.699136467373
9      0.75069339816
10    0.690879488242
11    0.653028655088
12    0.672679885077
13    0.638620890633
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you've constructed the DataFrame from `data`, the only extra thing you need to do is:

```
df.width = df.width.str[0]
```

This works because we're just using the `.str` accessor to get the first element of each list. Empty lists don't have a first element so `NaN` is returned for those rows.

You end up with a column of float64 values:

```
       width
0        NaN
1        NaN
2        NaN
3        NaN
4        NaN
5   0.648482
6   0.622417
7   0.768926
8   0.699136
9   0.750693
10  0.690879
11  0.653029
12  0.672680
13  0.638621
```

Note: if you want to display more decimal places, you'll need to adjust the float precision using `pd.set_options`.

Alternatively, you can process the list *before* you construct the DataFrame:

```
pd.DataFrame([x.get('width') for x in data], columns=['width'])
```

Comment: I like your alternative implementation using `x.get('width')`

Comment: Thanks! I see it's essentially the same as your method. I thought there might be a built-in Pandas way to do this (e.g. using `DataFrame.from_records` or similar) but I can't seem to find it...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension to extract the data from the array in the dictionary.  `d['width'][0]` will extract the first value from the array.  `if d['width'].shape[0]` will evaluate to `False` if the array is empty, in which case `None` is inserted.

```
>>> pd.DataFrame([d['width'][0] if d['width'].shape[0] else None for d in data], 
                 columns=['width'])
       width
0        NaN
1        NaN
2        NaN
3        NaN
4        NaN
5   0.648482
6   0.622417
7   0.768926
8   0.699136
9   0.750693
10  0.690879
11  0.653029
12  0.672680
13  0.638621
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this after getting the dataframe you posted:

```
def convert(x):
    if len(x) == 0:
            return np.nan
    else:
        return x[0]

 df['width'] = df['width'].apply(lambda x: convert(x))
```